# jQuery forms & updating info

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm attempting add some ajax to an existing script, all goes well for the first submit, but subsequent ones  are not working as expected.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_special_action_javascript');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'my_special_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'my_special_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_cart', 'my_cart_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_cart', 'my_cart_callback');
```

and prior to those I also have a `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

```
function my_special_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".addtocart").submit(function() {
  var data = {action: 'my_special_action',post:jQuery(this).serialize() };
  jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data,
  function(response){
   jQuery(".eshopajax").replaceWith(response);
  });
  function upCart(){
   var tdata = {action: 'my_cart'};
   jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", tdata,
   function(response){
    jQuery(".ajaxcart").replaceWith(response);
   });
  }
  setTimeout (upCart,500);
  return false;
 });
});
//]]>

</script>
<?php
}
```

Notes:
.addtocart is the class of the form (and there are going to be occasions when there are multiple forms on a page.)
.eshopax is a section within the form where I am displaying the response (though really I should add this via the script as well).
.ajaxcart is the cart in the widgets which I am trying to auto update.
setTimeout - added to slow things down for updating the cart, to allow the first process to finish.

Now as explained the above works as intended, **once**. But when I submit the form again, even with different values the display is no longer changed, yet the cart is updated (upCart) and no response text is visibly added. Additionally it doesn't appear to recognise changed form details.

So how do I reset things for it to recognise possible new form details? Additionally I don't think the *jQuery.post* in the upCart function is correct either (but it does work...).

any help appreciated.

(originally asked over on the WordPress support forums).

Answer (score 1):

ahh nvm, sorted it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.addtocart').submit(function(){
        var data = {action: 'my_special_action',post:$('.addtocart').serialize() };  
        $.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data,
        function(response){
            $(".eshopajax").insertAfter(this).fadeIn(100).html(response).fadeOut(3000);
            setTimeout (clearCart,200); 
            setTimeout (doRequest,500);  
            setTimeout (clearRequest,3000);  
        });
        function doRequest(){
            var tdata = {action: 'my_cart'};
            $.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", tdata,
            function(response){
                $(".ajaxcart").insertAfter(this).fadeIn(100).html(response);
            });
        }
        function clearRequest(){
            $(".eshopajax").empty();
        }
        function clearCart(){
            $(".ajaxcart").insert();
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: @Rich Pedley: what do you mean by "sorted it"? Did you fix the problem?